# Reselling Books

Tags: reference-request

Are there any good places for me to sell off my mathematics books online especially Springer and Dover books?

(I thought perhaps this was off topic, but then I thought everybody in math probably has the problem of having bought pricey books that they would prefer to get some money back for, at one point or another.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also list your books on amazon to sell rather than have amazon buy them from you

Answer (score 3):

I find it's pretty easy to sell books on e-bay.  Local used bookstores rarely go for good math books, unfortunately.

You might also want to try the big technical book resellers -- like Powell's Books, they're based in Portland Oregon.  Most on-line searches for books (like Google Books) will search Powell's stock.  So that might be one of the best options.

Answer (score 3):

I've been a seller on EBAY for years and they are out of control on fees. Also,people go to EBAY looking for a deal and you probably won't be able to make a good return on serious currently used textbooks on EBAY.You've got a much better chance of a good profit on Amazon.
***DON'T try and sell your books at buyback at the site-they'll rob you blind.***
You'll make much more becoming a seller and selling directly to customers.There are no fees directly-but Amazon charges 15 % per sale you make. You can also try a new site that's beginning to give EBAY serious competition called Bonanza. It's built a sizable and growing user base and it's fees are much lower then EBAY. The down side is you'll have to do your own advertising to drive people to the site. But given what you save on fees,it's worth the work and time investment.

Comment: Apparently someone who works for EBAY saw this post and downvoted it.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon will buy back a lot of textbooks at pretty fair rates. Check [this](http://www.amazon.com/Textbooks-Trade-In/b/ref=bhp_9p2_A_txbq410_05?ie=UTF8&node=2205237011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=center-6&pf_rd_r=0RH8PF985VSEMWFKG1SV&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1275995182&pf_rd_i=283155) out.

Comment: I've done this with many books.  If it's a book that is currently in widespread use as a textbook, you can often get a good price for it.  If it's not, you won't get much if anything.  I like it because it's incredibly easy.